# Persistent Priority Queue and Consumer Thread Pool in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, persistence, priority-queue

Here is the problem for which, I want to come up with an elegant solution. I would like to know your ideas and some libraries which can help me in getting a solution, using Java.

1. There will N number of **priority queues** which needs to be
   **persistent**(Currently DB, maybe later another solution).
2. There will be a **thread pool** which executes top elements of
   priority queues in a round robin fashion or preferably according to
   some priorities (a priority queue for thread pool).
3. Execution of elements in priority queues **is not synchronous**, for all
   elements to which I send a message through network and change the state
   of that queue to **waiting** until the arrival of a response coming from
   network. I want threads to keep processing other elements because
   response can arrive in very long amount of time.

Answer (score 2):

I would use a durable JMS queue. You can attach a thread pool of workers to the queue and queue up results/responses.

A simple to use JMS broker which can be embedded is ActiveMQ. You could also look at Apache Camel for routing these tasks, but it may be over kill for your requirements.

Comment: Wikipedia says that "Note that, contrary to what the name queue suggests, messages don't have to be delivered in the order sent. A JMS queue only guarantees that each message is processed only once." http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service Does durable JMS queue preserve order ?

Comment: Usually.  Some JMS servers have a performance option which delivery message sin batches.  This can result in out of order delivery in terms of what each worker sees. i.e. one worker might get tasks 0 to 9 and another 10 to 19 meaning job 10 could be processed before job 1.  There is a problem even you deliver one at a time, with multiple workers, there is no guarantee that job 0 will finish before job 1. The solution is to not need such a guarantee.  If you have multiple tasks which must be performed in order, put them all in the same message.